# Avoid rendering with *ngIf

Tags: angular

I have following code

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="false">
  {{test}}
</div>
```

`test` is deliberately not defined in my component. The `false` in `*ngIf` is for this example.
The site is working correctly, but after a while after I started my application I got following error message in terminal:

> Property 'test' does not exist on type XXX

I'm expecting that `{{test}}` will never be rendered. Unfortunately that's not the case. Any ideas, how can I avoid rendering of this test part?

Test is just example here, in real case I'm setting options with:

```
[options]="optionsList$ | async"
```

Comment: before to be rendered your application needs to be compiled, so declare your optionsList$ observable

Comment: but I don't need it neither in my component nor in my template. It will make my component own "not usefull" variable

Comment: can you build you application without errors?

Comment: probably I don't understand your question... all the best

Comment: you need to define `test` in your .component.ts, even if you aren't using/populating it anywhere. Your build is going to throw a fit saying you are trying to access a variable that isn't defined (even if it never appears in the DOM in the browser, your build still needs to know where all of the variables are coming from)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand good your question try this

```
[options]="(optionsList$ | async).length > 1"
```

Hopeful